# Using my own UIView in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview

I'm fairly new to iPhone development so please forgive me if this has been asked before.

I have just started playing with `UIScrollView`.  I want to have it work essentially the same as a `UITableView` but with more customised "cells", I've achieved this and it works well but I just wanted some clarification.

Initially when I was designing these "cells" I created just a UIView in Xcode which gave me just a nib file for the view, but this didn't help me when dealing with reference outlets and action handlers.

Then I created a `UIViewController` but I found myself just adding the view from the `UIViewController` to the `UIScrollView` - `[scrollView addSubview:myViewController.view]` - and this didn't feel right as it broke the "One `UIViewController` per screen" paradigm.

Then I went to create a `UIView` subclass where in the initialisation method I added the controls to my view (some labels and an image), positioning them based on how I designed it in the nib.

This last method works almost as I want it to, however it doesn't feel right that I can't visually design the cell and utilise the nib file.

How can I have my own custom `UIView` (not `UIViewController`) class that utilises a nib for the visuals that can be used in a `UIScrollView`.

If I'm way off on the use of `UIScrollView`'s please let me know where to look.

Thanks.

Comment: The possibilities of customizing cells in `UITableView` are limited only by your imagination. You do not need to use nib, you can design your own cells in code. [this book](http://www.amazon.com/Robert-Napier/e/B005KRBPQ6) by [this guy](http://stackoverflow.com/users/97337/rob-napier) has a chapter on getting `UITableView`s right, I highly recommend it.

Comment: I don't want to design the cells in code, I want to design them in nibs.  But the only way I could find to use them was to associate the nib with a UIViewController.

Comment: corect me if i m wrong... do u want to create Customize Cells in table view....???

Comment: Sorry I shouldn't have confused this - I am not using a table view, I am using a `UIScrollView` with my own `UIView`'s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a nib to make your own UIViews -

```
NSArray *nibContents = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyView" owner:self options:nil];

UIView *mySpecialView = [nibContents objectAtIndex:0];

[self addSubview:mySpecialView];
```

I've used this loads - it's certainly not necessary to go to the extreme of making a UIViewController for each view you need to add!

Comment: If I set the Custom Class of the UIView in Interface Builder, can I cast mySpecialView to be MyViewClass instead of UIView?

Comment: Ok I've done this, but I know there's something I need to do in the XIB to connect the view in the XIB to the view in the source code.. at the moment I'm getting the `"this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key image."` error when I try to load my view from the nib.  Suggestions?

Comment: In the Identity Inspector in IB, set the Custom Class to mySpecialView. In your class's interface, just make IBOutlets as you would for a viewController, and you can link them up in IB in the normal way. Your error sounds like the file owner is the wrong class.

Comment: How do I set that?  Under File's Owner I have set the Custom Class to my UIView's subclass and it's still giving me grief.

Comment: I get the same error, I am trying something similar, the custom uiview loads fine with just a uiimage in it - as soon as I try and connect a uibutton in the custom class it fails.
Did you have any luck, I will post if I find solution

Comment: just realised this was last year not last week, meh

Answer (score 0):

I think the method your trying to use here is really over complicating the problem. A UITableView actually contains a UIScrollView (though you cant access it) so it already does by default what you are trying to achieve. Also why do you think there should only be one view controller per view? In practice there are as many view controllers as necessary to make your app work and be organized.

What I would suggest is for you to use a UITableView and a custom UITableViewCell. You can design the cell in a nib easily, just delete the default view that comes with a new .xib and drag a UITableViewCell in its place. This does mean that you will need a ViewController for your custom UITableViewCell but the controller doesn't have to do anything except set the text of the cell if you want. Also you can easily reuse cells for memory purposes (though you can reuse plain views its not as memory friendly as cells - because Apple designed cells specifically to be reused.)

Do you need me to post any code to help with custom cells? Let me know Ill check back tomorrow if you do.

Hope this helps with your project, good luck.